# How do I stop the Magento cache increasing image filesize?

Tags: image, cache, gd2

This problem is specific to already well compressed jpegs.  When Magento is re-saving them to the cache, it increases the file size.  In some cases almost doubling the size compared to the original.  Obviously, the bigger the image, the greater the problem in absolute terms (of lost bandwidth/ performance).

This is somewhat infuriating!  How can I stop Magento messing with my images; and why on earth is it **adding** pixel data?!

I’m only allowed to post links to one example.  However, I could pick any image, it is increasing them all:

Original Image  - https://www.logsdirect.co.uk/media/catalog/product/p/e/peat-pallet-french-bottom_1.jpg (75 KB)

Cached version  -  https://www.logsdirect.co.uk/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/p/e/peat-pallet-french-bottom_1.jpg  (137 KB)

Answer (score 1):

Magento always re-render images for caching. In Class `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Image` there is an attribute called `$_quality` declared to 90.

Simply add in template where the helper is instantiated the Method `setQuality($value)`. e.g.

```
$_img = '<img id="image" src="'.$this->helper('catalog/image')->setQuality('70')->init($_product, 'image').'" alt="'.$this->escapeHtml($this->getImageLabel()).'" title="'.$this->escapeHtml($this->getImageLabel()).'" />';
```

Value needs to be between 0 and 100 as declared in `Varien_Image_Adapter_Abstract` Line 216-228.

hope that helps.

***appendum***: The Value is representing the grade of compression.

Comment: This is a useful starting point, thanks.  But is there no easy way to stop Magento re-rendering my already compressed and optimised images?

Comment: i didn't find any place or code snippet where to do this.

Comment: Changing the **$_quality** variable works to a certain extent, thanks for that.  However, I'm still not happy with the image rendering.  Hopefully, someone will have a better solution..

Answer (score 0):

Two ideas:

1. just use the original image instead of the `catalog/image` helper
2. Try [Perfect_Watermarks](https://github.com/magento-hackathon/Perfect_Watermarks) to use imagick instead of GD

Answer (score 0):

The following plugin has been recommended to optimise and compress all your Magento product cached images to get you great results in Google Speed Test. It allows you to integrate with several APIs like Resmush.it, ImageOptim, Kraken.IO to give you plenty of options to choose from

https://www.scommerce-mage.com/optimize-magento-product-cms-images.html